# Classes And Objects missing something

Tags: c#, class, object

Inside the class Test, there must be a public method `getLinkedList` and it shall receive nothing, but answer with a Node object.

You must create the Node class inside the Test class and it must be public. The Node class must have two instance variables. One that holds numbers and have the name TAL and one that holds a Node object and have the name NEXT.

Calling the getLinkedList the first time, it must answer with a Node object that has the TAL=1 and the NEXT=null

Calling the getLinkedList the second time, it must answer with a Node object that has the TAL=2 and the NEXT points to a Node with the TAL=1. This means that the first Node is placed last in the list and the newest Node is always at the front and its TAL value is the same as the numbers of Nodes in the list.

This is what I've done so far. Don't give me the answer direct please.

```
    public Node getLinkedList()
    {
        Node n = new Node();
        n.TAL = 1;
        n.NEXT = null;
        Node n1 = new Node();
        n1.TAL = 2;
        n.NEXT.TAL = n.TAL;
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public int TAL;
        public Node NEXT;
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? And this look like a homework question.

Comment: Homework, homework, homework...

Comment: Thats what i need to figure out, is it right or wrong? cause when I try it on my teachers website it wont work. and yes, its exercises, not homework ;)

Comment: @user3400937, define "it won't work". What happens and what are you expecting the program to do?

Comment: I mean, does the text above describe my code or am i missing something?

Comment: You should just put that code into the program and see what it does.  That would be the fastest way.  One tip, though, your `getLinkedList` method does not return a value.  You should be getting an error to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright without giving you too much, here's what you need to do with your get linked list function.

```
public Node GetLinkedList()
{
    //Check if your linked list is empty
    //If yes return your TAL = 1 node
    //If no create a new node with new TAL and return that
}
```

This should get you pointed in the right direction at least. You need some conditional logic in there